# How can I Update my form without hardcoding my mysqli query

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

My English is not the best but I try to describe my problem.

I want to update a PHP form. But my form is not hardcoded so I have problems with the update query. But I want to explain:

[first_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPsiR.png)

I have a database for my columns which are active or not active. The column "header_tabelle" includes the names of my headers. And the column "active" tells me if the column is active=1 or is not active=0.

I have a second table which includes data to this columns. I want show this database to.

[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRtOZ.png)

This table includes the same columns like the first table. Now I want to get the active column data into my form. For this I used the following query:

```
$db = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

     $sql = 'SELECT header_tabelle FROM tabelle_blocked_header WHERE active = "1"';
     $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);      
     $erg = "";
     $spalten = array();
     $nr1 = 0;
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $spalten[$nr1] = $row["header_tabelle"];
     $nr1 = $nr1 + 1;
     if ($erg == "") {
             $erg = $row["header_tabelle"];
         }
         else {
             $erg = $erg.', '.$row["header_tabelle"];
         }
     }
```

My Output here is the columns i want as the result; Example as:

> ID, Werkteil, Gebaude, Meisterei, Kurzbezeichnung, Kostenstelle, ASSMNG, Patchmanagement, Datensicherung, Firewall_Neuanlagen

Now I can insert this data into my Form. I do this like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT $erg FROM tabelle_werkteile WHERE ID = '$id' AND werkteil = '$werk' ";
$sql_result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
   foreach($row as $column => $value) {
```

And now to my Problem. How can i Update my data now ?

Comment: Are you asking how to update data in mysql with data from a form? There are _many_ guides/tutorials covering that.

Comment: no i have a special Problem. I have to Update a Form with columns who can change. So i cant hardcode the querry.

Comment: with my first querry i get name of colums where "active". With this Result i built a string to select data and post it into my form. But now i have a Problem to Update my Form because the columns can change if one of them are not active.

Comment: Then your question is very unclear. You need to update your query to include the database schema, example data, example result and describe the issue and in what cases your code won't work more clearly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have edited my Question i hope it is now clear what i mean

Comment: edit your question to give information about your db as @MagnusEriksson specified in his comment. Also, the last lines in your question are confusing, you're using SELECT to retrieve data from your database but speak of inserting data in a PHP form. Please be more clear on that point.